Is there a way, using Linq, to iterate through a list, check a condition, and send successes and failures to 2 different outputs?
Using Linq, you can iterate through a list, taking all items that meet a condition by using the Where method.  However, I have a list in which I want to take all items that meet a condition and do one thing, then take all items the do not meet a condition and do another.
I can imagine this type of scenario as looking somewhat like this:
var myList = new [] { 1,2,3,4,5 }
var result = myList
  .MyAwesomeSpecialWhereMethod(i => i % 2 == 0) // results in an object that has 2 lists, one containing successes and one containing failures
  .SelectSuccess(i => $"{i} is even") // modifies the success list into a list of strings
  .SelectFailure(i => $"{i} is odd") // modifies the failure list into a list of strings
  .Collect((success, failure) => success.Union(failure)) // aggregates the success and failure list using my lambda
Console.WriteLine(result)

The result of this would be
["2 is even","4 is even","1 is odd","3 is odd","5 is odd"] // (because I didn't bother sorting)

I think the case of "I have a list of things, and I want to do one thing with everything that matches this condition and another with everything that doesn't" is not an uncommon use case.  The benefit to this structure is not looping over the array twice with 2 separate Wheres.  I can accomplish this with a loop
foreach (var i in myList){
  if (i%2 == 0){
    evens.Add(i);
  } else {
    odds.Add(i);
  }

However I'm wondering if there's is a more "LINQy" way to do it.

It may not be necessary to create two separate paths. The .Select() can contain complex logic and one of the following options may suit your needs: .Select(i => i % 2 == 0 ? $"{i} is even" : $"{i} is odd"),  .Select(i => AwesomeCheck(i) ? SuccessResult(i) : FailureResult(i)) or .Select(i => { Complex logic that may include an if-else ...; return result; }).  No follow-up .Union() is needed. (I also thing the .SpecialWhere() answer below is a good option that separates out the clutter.)

You can combine .Select() and .ToLookup() like this.
List<int> input = [1,2,3,4,5];
var result = input
      .Select((item, index) => new { isEven = index % 2 == 0, item })
      .ToLookup(
          i => i.isEven,
          i => i.item);

OR use .GroupBy() and ToDictionary() like this.
List<int> input = [1,2,3,4,5];
var output = input
    .GroupBy(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());

And call it like,
Console.Writeline(results[true]);  // even
Console.Writeline(results[false]); // odd


Your approach won't only be looping over the list once. For every LINQ method you call you'll be looping over the list. You've ordered your result with the successes followed by the failures, but if the order of the result doesn't particularly matter or can be kept the same as the input order, and you don't need the success and failure results to be two separate lists, I'd like to suggest this solution using a single enumeration and a custom extension method for IEnumerable:
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> SpecialWhere<T, TOut>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> condition, Func<T, TOut> success, Func<T, TOut> failure)
    {
        foreach (T e in enumerable)
            yield return condition(e) ? success(e) : failure(e);
    }
}

Which is then used like so:
int[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = a.SpecialWhere(
    i => (i & 1) == 0,
    i => $"{i} is even",
    i => $"{i} is odd"
    );

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', result));

To give 1 is odd,2 is even,3 is odd,4 is even,5 is odd. The condition is passed as the first parameter, then the function to transform successful values, then the function to transform failure values.

Aggregate can do this too
var (evens, odds) = numbers.Aggregate(
            (Evens: new List<int>(), Odds: new List<int>()),
            (tuple, num) =>
            {
                (num % 2 == 0 ? tuple.Evens : tuple.Odds).Add(num);
                return tuple;
            });

Aggregate takes a seed value, here a tuple that contains two lists, and for every number in the original list invokes the delegate. The delegate receives the tuple and the number as arguments, it checks the number to be even or odd and picks the relevant list out of the tuple accordingly, then that list's Add method is called to add the number. It's a requirement that the delegate you supply to Aggregate returns the tuple that values are accumulating into, and the value you return will be supplied next time (this is so that you can aggregate into immutable things like strings and they will actually grow)
At the end of the Agg, the tuple will be returned as the value and he code above deconstructs it into two variables called even and odd, making the whole op a fairly compact one-liner way of generating your two separated lists, having traversed the list only once
There is no shame in using a foreach, though - LINQ is a hammer but not every problem is a nail - your foreach approach is highly likely to be understood at first glance by a wider set of developers than something like this and that is a considerable benefit

Wanted to point out, via another answer, that the very specific case presented in the question, of your union, means this can also be simply done by OrderBy
LINQ generally preserves the input order absent any other override so your foreach loop that processes the input in order, moving items into one of two lists, then prints first one list then the other means that in each list the items are in the same order as they were in the input
An input of 1,2,3,4 realises two lists of 1,3 and 2,4
As LINQ preserves order, calling
    myList.OrderBy(n => n%2)

Will generate a sequence that prints out the same as your Union of evens then odds did. The n%2 reduces the number to either a 0 or 1, and in ascending logic, means that evens (resolves to 0) clump together before odds (resolve to 1). There is no other logic to further alter the order (perform a "then by") of the items so the evens end up in the original order they were in the input list, ahead of the odds which are also "then by" their original order

But then there's no way to make the distinction afterwards.

@GertArnold it's true, but it's not really clear in the question as to whether that's a requirement because the first code block in the question  unions the split to a single result array. It's why I specifically made this clear in the first paragraph of the answer; if the result is to be a union (all) then it it is simply an ordering exercise. For a result that is formed of two separate lists, I presented an alternative answer using Aggregate
